# heroku deploy java telegram

Tags: java, telegram, бот, heroku

"Бьюсь как рыба об лед..." 
Написал телеграм-бот который на лок.машине работает и телега дает ответ. Ниписан код на чистой джаве.
Деплою на хероку и тут два пути: - не деплой и - нет ответа

Прошу помочь!
https://github.com/RomanSkrypnyk-main/wea-bot-telegram - репозиторий

Основная проблема после Build succeeded в
Application Logs Heroku ето Error: **Main method not found in class**

Procfile - `worker: java -cp target/classes/:target/dependency/* com.company.Main`
перепробовал куча вариантов procfile файла и указания класса, jar-файла и т.д.

pom.xml - зависимости локально работают но не знаю правильно ли написаны для деплоя.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>wea-bot</groupId>
    <artifactId>wea-bot-telegram</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>             
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
         
         <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.3</version>
            </plugin>
                 
                 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                    <programs>
                        <program>
                            <mainClass>com.company.Main</mainClass>
                            <name>wea_bot</name>
                        </program>
                    </programs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assemble</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>      
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Приведены не все логи но...
https://github.com/RomanSkrypnyk-main/wea-bot-telegram/blob/main/wea-bot-telegram-log_HEROKU.txt здесь все.

```
2021-04-29T19:06:43.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user skrypnyk.rma@gmail.com

2021-04-29T19:07:07.132806+00:00 app[api]: Release v50 created by user skrypnyk.rma@gmail.com

2021-04-29T19:07:07.132806+00:00 app[api]: Deploy ae5b8722 by user skrypnyk.rma@gmail.com

2021-04-29T19:07:08.485124+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2021-04-29T19:07:09.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded

2021-04-29T19:07:12.094693+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `java -cp target/classes/:target/dependency/* com.company.Main`

2021-04-29T19:07:12.824096+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up

2021-04-29T19:07:15.067430+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1

2021-04-29T19:07:15.012299+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Main method not found in class com.company.Main, please define the main method as:

2021-04-29T19:07:15.012338+00:00 app[worker.1]:    public static void main(String[] args)

2021-04-29T19:07:15.012349+00:00 app[worker.1]: or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

2021-04-29T19:07:14.705785+00:00 app[worker.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UseContainerSupport -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 

2021-04-29T19:07:15.132072+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed

2021-04-29T19:21:41.540401+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2021-04-29T19:21:45.926364+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `java -cp target/classes/:target/dependency/* com.company.Main`

2021-04-29T19:21:46.570674+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up

2021-04-29T19:21:51.614988+00:00 app[worker.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UseContainerSupport -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 

2021-04-29T19:21:51.836825+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Main method not found in class com.company.Main, please define the main method as:

2021-04-29T19:21:51.836827+00:00 app[worker.1]:    public static void main(String[] args)

2021-04-29T19:21:51.836886+00:00 app[worker.1]: or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

2021-04-29T19:21:51.980834+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1

2021-04-29T19:21:52.047065+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

*Вывод: *

- worker:java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.company.Main **/** worker: java -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp ./target/classes:./target/dependency/* com.company.Main **/** worker sh:target/bin/wea_bot - не помогло
- heroku ps:scale web=1 - сработало но бот молчит или ошибка по логам
- вставлял зависимости и в Procfile https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java
- деплой Build succeeded но бот молчит ошибка по логам.

Все спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.`public class Main extends TelegramLongPollingBot`- вот как надо было написать и обьявить Main файл котоый не находило; изменён main!
пишем class Main и библиотека, я не правильно написал Main; был без extends, а указал extends возле psvm что не верно.

2.`procfile - worker: sh target/bin/wea_bot`
имя бота из pom.xml смотрим `<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId> <mainClass>com.company.Main</mainClass>                            <name>wea_bot</name>`

3. бот задеплоился и работает.
4. спасибо.